# How to split this value 31.07?

Tags: java, android

I know how to split decimal values. But I'm little bit confused how to split 31.07 or 71.008 something like this. if I'm using this below code , the value splitted like this 31 and 0.7

**I need a Solution to be:**  31 and 0.07. How can I solve my problem?

Here java code:

```
    String decimal_value = String.format("%.2f", update_fare);
           String[] arr = decimal_value.split("\\.");
           if (arr.length == 2) {
               int[] intArr = new int[2];
               String before_decimal = String.valueOf(intArr[0] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
               String after_decimal = String.valueOf(intArr[1] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
               fare_tv.setText(String.valueOf(before_decimal));
               fare_tv_decimal.setText(String.valueOf(after_decimal));
               System.out.println("----------------updated fare intArr[0]---------" + intArr[0]);
               System.out.println("----------------updated fare intArr[1]---------" + intArr[1]);

           }
```

Comment: Simply use b= a%1 and ans=a-b

Comment: Can you please explain briefly.

Answer (score 1):

if A is your number, for example - A = 31.03,

And you want to split it like 31 and 0.03 into B and C, you can do something like that:

```
A = 31.03; // your number
B = a%1; // XX.00
C = A-B; // 00.XX
```

Comment: I need to Show this value in my Textview. befor point text sholud be bigger size and  after point text sholud be show smaller size.So i need 31 and .07

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
    String value = "31.07";

    String[] values = value.split("\\.");

    if(values.length==2)
    {
         int[] intArr = new int[2];


         String value1 = values[0];
         String value2 = "0."+values[1];

         fare_tv.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
         fare_tv_decimal.setText(String.valueOf(value2));

         intArr[0] = Integer.parseInt(value1);
         intArr[0] = Integer.parseInt(value2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working only with positive doubles, the following code might help you:

```
int total  = (int)update_fare; //gets the whole part
double rem = update_fare - total; //gets the value after the dot
```

You can then use a proper formatter to convert them to strings as follows:

```
 String rem_str = String.format("%.2f", rem);
 String total_str = String.format("%d", total);
```

However, be careful of using this technique when dealing with negative numbers. You need to change some parts based on the sign of the value.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
String value = "31.07";

String[] values = value.split("\\.");

if(values.length==2)
    {
    double[] intArr = new double[2];


    String value1 = values[0];
    String value2 = "0."+values[1];

    fare_tv.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
    fare_tv_decimal.setText(String.valueOf(value2));

    intArr[0] = Double.parseDouble(value1);
    intArr[1] = Double.parseDouble(value2);
    System.out.println("----------------updated fare intArr[0]---------" + intArr[0]);
    System.out.println("----------------updated fare intArr[1]---------" + intArr[1]);
}
```